# Add spacer lines in a text file's list with Python

Tags: python, line-breaks

I have a text file with a list of entries, like this:

```
entry 
entry 
entry 
entry
```

and I would like to open, change and then write the file like this

```
entry 

entry 

entry 

entry
```

Because there are several duplicates, I've used this method to remove the duplicate entries, but it also removed the spaces between them.

```
open("uniqueenties.txt",'w').writelines(set(open("oldentries.txt",'r').readlines()))
```

Can I add something to the code so it retains the spaces between the lines, or add them after the cleanup, before saving the file?

Comment: Your whole sample input consists of duplicates. Please [edit] your question and provide a sample of real input and the required output.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve - please add some example output (best real data)

Answer (score 0):

```
open("uniqueenties.txt",'w').writelines([(f + '\n') for f in open("oldentries.txt",'r').readlines()])
```

Might be also a good idea to split your line in 2 and use variables like so :

```
input_file = open("oldentries.txt",'r')
oldentries = input_file.readlines()
newentries = [(f + '\n') for f in oldentries]
output_file = open("uniqueenties.txt",'w')
output_file.writelines(newentries)
```

It is more readable and evolutive in general this kind of way.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Use this code

f = open("file.txt").read()

txt = t.replace("\n", "\n\n")

wf = open("changed.txt", "w")

wf.write(txt)